# Caught error in autotex process: *** Error: No postscript to move ***

Tags: arxiv

I want to upload a paper to arXiv, but I face with the following error:

```
verbose]: Creating arXiv submission AutoTeX object
[verbose]: *** Using TeX Live 2020 ***
[verbose]: Calling arXiv submission AutoTeX process
[verbose]: TeX/AutoTeX.pm: admin_timeout = minion
[verbose]: No tex files present, going to hope we can process as a postscript or dvi only package.
[verbose]: All done.

[verbose]: AutoTeX process succeeded
[verbose]: Processing DVI
[verbose]: There does not appear to be anything to move for dvi...Odd
[verbose]: Processing postscript
[verbose]: Creating AutoTeX file for acmart_primary
[error]: *** Error: No postscript to move ***
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically this occurs because you uploaded multiple subdirectories that contain your tex, and nothing in the document root. arXiv cannot process such documents (it doesn't traverse subdirectories looking for the main tex file), so it aborts.
To fix this, you should minimally have your main tex file (the file that contains the `\documentclass` directive) at the top of your source tree. Remember to update any file paths in the document once you've moved the file.

Note that this forum is more for general questions related to latex. For specific support related to arXiv submissions see [the help pages](https://info.arxiv.org/help/contact.html) for how to contact us with your submit-id.